# WordPress Stats keeps showing non-existent post as a top post?

Tags: 404-error, statistics

For some reason, one of my top posts as reported by [WordPress Stats](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/) is actually non-existent...

What I see is:

> #2147483647 (loading title)

and it links to "...?p=2147483647" which returns a 404.

Now a bit of background info:

- I'm actually using the following permalink settings: **/%category%/%postname%/**
- Stats for other posts seem to be fine
- I migrated from tumblr to WordPress

The odd thing is looking into the database where the posts are stored I can not find any reference to that particular ID.

Also, I appear to have several 'duplicates' of posts in the database - the difference being in a couple of fields (I'm guessing versioning or something?)

I've googled a bit, and the closest I've seem to come is: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-for-id-loading-title-coming-back-from-stats_get_csv-function

However, that seems to assume that the ID actually exists, but WordPress/WordPressStats is just for some reason unable to get the title.

So does anyone know why WordPress Stats is listing this non-existent page? (It comes #2 in all time top posts!)

Thanks!

Comment: I guess the problem came with the migration which failed in some point (How many posts have you got? - 2.147.483.647 is quite a high number). The "dublicates" you're talking about maybe post revisions.

Comment: Not many posts at all, in fact 9 all up. First post has ID of: 2142165720, and most recent post has ID of: 2165214978. I think these IDs are taken from tumblr IDs. I've checked tumblr too - no posts that correspond to that ID!

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you using? and What version of Wordpress Stats are you  using?

Comment: I'm using WordPress 3.1.3 and WordPress Stats 1.8.1. I have another blog using the same combination and has no problems.

Comment: 2147483647 = 2^31 - 1. I suspect you hit a counting bug somewhere.

Comment: @Otto i think you may be spot on! According to: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-importer-importer-fails-for-post_ids-over-php_int_max-of-2147483647, posts after mid-Dec on tumblr will have postIDs greater than MAX_INT. A good majority of my posts were after mid-Dec, and the 2nd highest ranking post is one posted in early-Dec (postID < MAX_INT)... will investigate and post back with results. Thanks :)

Comment: update: after creating backups, and playing around with some SQL and lots of find/replace, I have now 'reset' all my postIDs :) Blog still appears to be 'healthy' - links etc work. If this works, will post what I did in detail.

Comment: @Otto - if you post an answer post with your observation with the comment, I would be more than happy to accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out WordPress doesn't deal well with post IDs > 2^31.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16445

Tumblr in particular has post IDs greater than this, so it's not recommended to keep old post IDs from Tumblr on an import.

Answer (score 2):

After Otto's awesome observation, some SQL trickery I believe I have now fixed the problem :)

### The Problem

I was using tumblr and transferred my posts to WordPress. However, since approx mid-Dec tumblr postIDs were greater than 32-bit MAX_INT (2147483647). Of course, I had several posts created after mid-Dec, thus they all had postIDs greater than MAX_INT - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-importer-importer-fails-for-post_ids-over-php_int_max-of-2147483647

For whatever reason, my posts imported fine, however the WordPress Stats did not like these insanely large numbered postIDs, thus I experienced the problem outlined in my question.

### The Fix

> WARNING!!!
>
> Fiddling around with postIDs/database can potentially screw up your blog - linking etc. So perform at your own risk!
>
> I was very lucky that this was a fairly new blog - 0 comments and only 18 posts... so overall it was still fairly simple.
>
> Remember to back up, incase something horrible goes wrong!

To solve this problem, I backed up WordPress, cleaned up my WordPress database, exported all tables that had references to postIDs, reduced the postID values, reset the auto-increment value, re-inserted the data.

**Backing up:** I did an XML export and also performed a full backup of the blog via cPanel.

**Cleanup database:** There was a useless rows (for post revisions) in the database, so to simplify the later steps I first cleaned up my database using the following plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cleanup/

**Export tables:** Going into phpAdmin through cPanel, I went through each table and any that had references to postIDs I exported into a **.sql** file, remember to include the drop tables if exists option. The tables I ended up needing to export were: wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships.
***!!! NOTE: I was lucky that this is a relatively new blog. So there were 0 comments, thus did not need to worry about comments!!!***

**Reducing postIDs:** Using numbers (ie. excel) I first made a mapping of the old/new postIDs. (eg: 2165214909->3, 2165214895->4 etc). With the old/new postIDs 'set', I went through each of the exported .sql files and did find/replace all. *Note: it appears that attachments in posts also have their own postID so it can be a tad confusing*

**Reset auto-increment number:** In the wp_post.sql file, I reset the auto-increment value to something like 30. That way the next blog will have a postID starting at 30. If you don't reset this, any new posts created will still have high postIDs and you'll be faced with the same problem.

**Re-inserting data:** Back in phpAdmin, using the .sql files containing the new postIDs I imported the data back in. Since in the export I chose to drop table if it exists, it cleared the existing tables and inserted with the "new" data.

After doing all of this, I did a quick sanity check to make sure everything was fine. Public blog - clicked around, made sure images were there, searching works, tags worked etc. Admin section - check that when you hover over 'Edit' it shows the correct new postID, creating a new post uses the new auto-increment id, and of course (after a few days) that the WordPress stats was back to normal.

All checks passed, so I think the fix has worked :)